# what is the difference between imap and pop3

Tags: macos, mac, pop3

I want to save my emails on Mail.app locally and not on gmail servers. How would I set incoming and outgoing pop/imap?

I know there is articles online but I can't understand how to do that in Mail.app on Mac and also I'm pretty slow.

Comment: Can you share the document which you referred?

Comment: Check [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203995) apple support page.

Comment: [Here](https://help.1and1.com/e-mail-and-office-c37589/manually-configuring-e-mail-clients-c85091/manually-set-up-e-mail-with-mac-os-x-mail-a726021.html) it is given step by step.

Comment: thanks for the support page. the answer didnt help me with the configuration much. I DON'T want to save the emails on google for sharing with my phone.

Comment: Follow @vembutech 's step by step, but use the info from [here](https://www.lifewire.com/what-are-the-gmail-pop3-settings-1170853)

Answer (score -1):

If you are on the mac go to

1. **System Preferences** and choose **Internet Accounts** [image: System Preferences]
2. Click the little plus sign at the bottom '**+**' and then choose **Google**
   [image: Choose account]
3. Sign in into your Google account
   [image: Google signin]
4. At the end of the sign in choose mail to be synced
   [image: Sync mail]

Comment: I don't think this meets OP's stated goal of not leaving his email on Google's servers. This method sets up IMAP access to his Gmail account, not POP.

Comment: Does he explicitly required pop ? I think he just wants to access his gmail account from his local machine using the Mail.app

Comment: 'Local' would imply POP. IMAP likes to do its own thing - which I personally cannot abide, so I stay on POP for precisely that reason.